# Lever "paradox"?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

Let's say we have a lever with two weights A and B with the same mass overlapping at the midpoint. Suppose they start to separate with each other at the speed of light simultaneously. From our point of view, A,B have the same mass and displacement, therefore the lever balances itself. From A's point of view, A is not moving, B is moving, therefore by special relativity B has a larger mass than A, therefore the lever loses its balance. It seemed odd to me at first and I couldn't explain it. But now I've wrapped my head around and I think this reasoning should be falsified by nothing but general relativity, since a gravitational field is presented. Let's simply this gravitational field as a place where every point produces the same accelerate. First of all, I wonder: How can we set up the metric?

Comment: The short answer is:  you're failing to consider the relativity of simultaneity.  In the lever's frame, the two masses have the same displacement from the midpoint.  But, in either masses' frame, this isn't the case.  I believe G. Paily arrives at the same conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe we need to invoke GR for this. So, to state your problem with variables, two objects $A$ and $B$ with identical rest masses $m_{0}$ start at the origin at $t=0$ and then head in opposite directions along the $X$ axis with equal speeds $v$, $A$ moving in the positive direction and $B$ in the negative direction. To an observer $O$ stationary at the center, the two particles increase in both distance and mass, and so the 'lever' remains balanced, or to put it another way, the center of mass remains at the origin. What is observed from $A$'s perspective?

According to $A$, her distance from $O$ (position with respect to $O$) is given by $x_{O/A}=vt$. And the speed of $B$ is given by
$$v_{B/A} = \frac{v_{B/O}-v_{A/O}}{1-\frac{v_{B/O}v_{A/O}}{c^{2}}}$$
$$=\frac{-v-v}{1+\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}$$
$$=\frac{-2v}{1+\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}\equiv -u.$$
So from A's perspective, the mass of $B$ is given by $m_{0}\gamma_{u}=\frac{m_{0}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$. And thus the center of mass as a function of time $t$ is given by:
$$x_{com}=\frac{m_{0}[-(u-v)]t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^{2}}{c^{2}}}}+m_0vt,$$ which, after some algebra, you can show is equal to zero. In particular, note that 
$$\gamma_{u} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}} = \frac{1+\frac{v^2}{c^{2}}}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$

Short version: $A$ sees $B$ as heavier than her, but not as far from the origin/fulcrum as her. Thus the torques still balance out.

Comment: "After some algebra" I have difficulties showing the center of mass equal to zero, Could you specify yours please?

Comment: Whoops, I had typed one of the signs wrong while typing up my answer (it's in the expression for $u$). I've changed it, and expanded on one of the steps. You should be able to do it now.

Comment: G. Paily: "_the two particles increase in [...] mass_" -- Your (algebraically correct) calculation can instead be based on the argument that "the total energy $\gamma~m~c^2$ contributes to the weight". "_the center of mass remains at the origin._" -- Right, and this settles the symmetric case described in the OP question. However, when considering a suitable asymmetric case, e.g. $$v_{B/O} := 2~v_{A/O} \qquad m_{0B} := \frac{1}{2} m_{0A} \sqrt{\frac{1 - 4~v_{A/O}^2/c^2}{1 - v_{A/O}^2/c^2}}$$ then the (finite) "response speed" of the lever is relevant (and I'd expect it'll tilt towards $A$).

Comment: Well technically there is no such thing as a rigid body in relativity, which is why I framed it in terms of the center of mass of the system.